# I need to get the underlying java.sql.Connection from Vert.x's SQLConnection

Tags: java, liquibase, vert.x

I'm using vert.x's JDBCClient to get my database connections and it only gives me io.vertx.ext.sql.SQLConnection or io.vertx.reactivex.ext.sql.SQLConnection and none of them extends java.sql.Connection.

In order to call Liquibase from a verticle I need a java.sql.Connection.

I know that Vert.x uses C3Po on behind but I was not able to find any method that could give me the underlying connection.

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on a recent version, `SQLConnection` has an `unwrap` method. As indicated in the [docs](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/sql/SQLConnection.html#unwrap--):

> `default <N> N unwrap()`
>
> Return the underlying Connection object if available. This is not mandated to be implemented by the clients.

The JDBCClient should return a `java.sql.Connection`. Don't forget to call `close` on the original `SQLConnection` after usage.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried with:

```
final JDBCClient dbClient = JDBCClient.createShared(vertx, new JsonObject()
            .put("url", dbUrl)
            .put("user", user)
            .put("password", pass)
            .put("driver_class", "you.driver")
            .put("max_pool_size", 30)
    );
```

Comment: sure, the vert.x jdbc API only returns io.vertx.ext.sql.SQLConnection that do not extends java.sql.Connection

Comment: But why do you need java.sql.Connection ? It is blocking.

Comment: As he mentioned in the question, Liquibase requires a `java.sql.Connection`