# I need to get the underlying java.sql.Connection from Vert.x's io.vertx.sqlclient.SqlConnection (new vertx jdbc api)

Tags: java, jdbc, vert.x, ojdbc

I need to get the underlying java.sql.Connection from Vert.x's io.vertx.sqlclient.SqlConnection (new vertx jdbc api)

Here is the solution for vertx legacy jdbc api solved by @tsegismont

[I need to get the underlying java.sql.Connection from Vert.x's SQLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49650083/i-need-to-get-the-underlying-java-sql-connection-from-vert-xs-sqlconnection/49666826#49666826)

this doesn't work for new vertx jdbc sql-client as there is no unwrap method.
need help to get the underlying java.sql.Connection.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible with the current API. Can you file an issue please?

Comment: Thanks @tsegismont
here is the issue create for this question
https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vertx-sql-client/issues/1088